# Android programming, how to change voice frequency

Tags: android

I want to play a WAV file at another frequency (300hz, 500hz... ) on Android. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: I tried the methods of MediaPlayer but it not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [SoundPool](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) class.

It has a `setRate(int streamID, float rate)` method. Setting the rate to 1.0 will play at normal speed - setting rate of 2.0 will play at twice the speed and so on.

Changing playback rate will change frequency. If you have a plain tone of 100Hz then a rate of 3.0 will change it to 300Hz and a rate of 5.0 will change it to 500Hz for example.

Comment: Thank for answer. But I want keep the current speed. Is there any way to do so?